# How to intersect two planes?

Tags: python, scripting, geometry, mathematics

I am trying to use the [`geometry.intersect_plane_plane`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/mathutils.geometry.html?highlight=geometry.intersect_plane#mathutils.geometry.intersect_plane_plane) function, but I can't use the results properly.

On this tryout, we have two points (`f0c` and `f1c`) extracted with `obj.data.poligons[idx].center` and two normals (`n0` and `n1`), extracted with `obj.data.polygons[idx].center` + `obj.data.polygons[idx].normal`, where `idx` is equal to the polygon index (`0` and `1`, on this case) from object `obj`

From the `geometry.intersect_plane_plane(f0c,n0,f1c,n1)` we got the result "isec" point/vector... It doesn't make any sense to me :(

[image]

Can someone help me to understand what is the result and how to "trace a line" or construct a edge in the intersection?

Comment: your mistake is summing the center point with the polygon normal to get n0/1 , you 'll have to set n0/1 = polygon center and that's all, the result is a point and a vector which can be used to trace the line ( don't sum them also)